# Magento 2 password format

Tags: magento2, password

What is the format of a Magento 2 password? For example:

> 0504c745003c3d3e7ddc542ae510e1122b7e351435fbdc2986587f9ef295d6af:pfcFuoTL2qienx37PGFHOhWYoXEQwyxo:1

Is it (salt + password):salt:1 ?
Because I've tried creating a `SHA256` hashed password through a python function with that format, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

This is the method that [hashes a password](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php#L143):

```
public function getHash($password, $salt = false, $version = self::HASH_VERSION_LATEST)
{
    if ($salt === false) {
        return $this->hash($password);
    }
    if ($salt === true) {
        $salt = self::DEFAULT_SALT_LENGTH;
    }
    if (is_integer($salt)) {
        $salt = $this->random->getRandomString($salt);
    }
    return implode(
        self::DELIMITER,
        [
            $this->hash($salt . $password),
            $salt,
            $version
        ]
    );
}
```

Where `$this->hash` is this:

```
public function hash($data, $version = self::HASH_VERSION_LATEST)
{
    return hash($this->hashVersionMap[$version], $data);
}
```

For customers the version parameter is not specified so it will use `sha256`

So `0504c745003c3d3e7ddc542ae510e1122b7e351435fbdc2986587f9ef295d6af:pfcFuoTL2qienx37PGFHOhWYoXEQwyxo:1` means

- `0504c745003c3d3e7ddc542ae510e1122b7e351435fbdc2986587f9ef295d6af` - sha256(salt + password)
- `pfcFuoTL2qienx37PGFHOhWYoXEQwyxo` - salt
- 1 . encryption method from the `\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor` [which is](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php#L25) `sha256`