# Magento 2 SHA1 Password is not Accepting after Migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration

I have Migrated Magento 1.9.1.0 website in Magento 2.2.4,all data is migrated successfully.

When I am trying to login from front-end with existing old customer(Magento1)
it generating error

"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."

While it is working fine for Newly creating customers in Magento 2.

I have debugged in Database customer_entity table and found that old Magento 1 was using SHA1 for password hashing and its length is "40"  + salt = 73 character.Since magento 1 default using MD5 technique but in our Magento code old developers override core file and changed below code

```
class CD_Core_Model_Encryption extends Mage_Core_Model_Encryption
{
    /**
     * Hash a string
     *
     * @param string $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function hash($data)
    {
        return sha1($data);
    }
}
```

Hence all passwords in Magento 1 saved in SHA1 format.

passwords are after migrated

```
6de015050ee16e5451019072f77f2bf50c3c02bc:VLAyPWtkZsHa00UMCWrFNtJ1ARoBp4Wc
```

Above password are not accepted in Magento 2 when login

Please help anybody how to support SHA1 password in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are aware of possible solutions But let me clarify it:

**Solution 1:** *Easy Quick Solution*

what **alan Storm** Suggested:- 
[image]

1. Ask your customer to change password by sending them reset password link.
2. Reset all Password Manually or by script & send them.

**How you can do that:** (`put in root folder & run` script for send password reset link to all customers)

```
include('app/bootstrap.php'); // add bootstrap file

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend'); 

$_customers = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');
$customerCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
$customerCollection->load();   // get customers
$i = 0;
foreach ($customerCollection as $customers) {

    $email = $customers->getData('email');

    try {
            $_customers->initiatePasswordReset($email, AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            echo __('We\'re unable to send the password reset email.');
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $i . " Email :-" . $email . " Mail Sent";

    $i++;
}
```

**Solution 2**. ( Not Recommended but also work)

*Hash algorithm can not change from one to another (md5 to sh1/sh2)*. Magento2 doesn't support SHA1 (`deprecated`)

> Hashing algorithms are one-way i.e. They cannot be reversed unlike Encryption-Decryption algorithms.

you can't get back string(password) But you can check same hash value by `brute force`.

Magento 1.x has stored password similar to

`password =`353dc2ba6108461cf3468184bdd0e174:LM 
=>  md5($password.$salt):salt.

**Pseudo code**

```
if( md(5) [password [1].userenteredpasswd])==password [0])
{
# User Authenticated
}
```

**in your case**

```
6de015050ee16e5451019072f77f2bf50c3c02bc:VLAyPWtkZsHa00UMCWrFNtJ1ARoBp4Wc
```

`sh1(md5($password.$salt)):sha1(salt)`

As Magento2 store in this way

`5ca6a208eba1be74251419d22399925c01fbe36f72c5b472d110c40c119b8709:QTwASvDZV6kKPNCl8eHZGZfF1U8NaoRB:1`

**hash('SHA-256', $salt . $password):$salt:1**

**Hash Value:(random 32 bit character):(Hashing algorithm version default:1)**

- MD5 produces 128 bit(16 byte) hash value(supported by magento 1.x , 2.x).
- SHA-1 produces 160 bit hash value.
- SHA-2(SHA-256) produces 256 bit hash value(supported by magento 2.x).

**What you have to do now:** 
authenticate users by extra step and also save in similar  manner.

**Pseudo code**

```
if( sh2(sh1(md(5) [password [1].userenteredpasswd])))==password [0])
    {
    # User Authenticated
    }
```

**Want to change in core files to support `SHA1`?**

> it's hashing password and  encrypt/decrypt library using cryptographic algorithms.
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php

```
                 or
```

**write a plugin for extra authenticate step**

> for `\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface::authenticate()`.
>    check this 
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/AccountManagementInterface.php

Comment: Hi @lalit,In which function we will require to write above condition if( sh2(sh1(md(5) [password [1].userenteredpasswd])))==password [0])  in file path vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php   ?

Comment: @akgola I don't know exactly how you hash & encrypt your password in magento1 based on  match that hash value with my generated hash (SHA-1) I confirm it's sha-1. Can you create user in ur modified m1 and share with me hash value so I can create on my system to check solution works.(update also core file changes).

Comment: @akgola `getHash` and `hash`

Comment: Hello @lalit, Please share updated function so we can implement it properly.

Comment: @akgola Please write a plugin for custom authentication. Don't change core files as it will make big trouble in future upgrade. There's no shortcuts to solve problems. it will take efforts if you want me to write plugin for you give me some time .. I will update soon..

Answer (score 1):

After migrating database from magento1 to magento2, customer login problem occurs, to solve that problem just go to a file name encryptor.php in the vendor folder (Path) vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php and change isValidHash() function like below.

```
public function isValidHash($password, $hash)
       { 
          try { 

            $this->explodePasswordHash($hash);

           foreach ($this->getPasswordVersion() as $hashVersion) {

            if ($hashVersion == '0') {

                $recreated = current(explode(':', $hash));

            }else if ($hashVersion === self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13) {
                $recreated = $this->getArgonHash($password, $this->getPasswordSalt());
            } else {

                $recreated = $this->generateSimpleHash($this->getPasswordSalt() . $password, $hashVersion);
            }

            $hash = $this->getPasswordHash();
            error_log('password changing technique ======');
            error_log(print_r($recreated,true));
            error_log(print_r($hash,true));
        }
    } catch (\RuntimeException $exception) {
        //Hash is not a password hash.
        $recreated = $this->hash($password);
    }

    return Security::compareStrings(
        $recreated,
        $hash
    );
}
```

the above change wont cause any issue because once user login with above method, magento2 will change the password hash to its proper password format and you can see difference in customer_entity table in magento2 database.

Comment: this works. try it, if your M1 passwords are not working after migrating. Or if you copy directly from DB make sure you add ":0" to the end of the password_hash before trying to login on m2

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 by default uses Sha256 for encryption.

Refer to [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147821/magento-2-password-format)

You can review the same in the file `Encryptor.php` located at `vendor\magento\framework\Encryption`

One way you can do it override the file using preference method like shown [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162442/how-to-import-md5-password-to-magento-2/162480) and change the encryption format to `sha1`.

You can further Refer to `public function getHash` and `public function hash`

A way out for you to allow existing customers access can be to use plugin method like Sinisa mentioned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162442/how-to-import-md5-password-to-magento-2/162480) extending `\Magento\Customer\Model\Authentication`. You can also use the plugin created by him and change the `md5` hash to `sha1`. There may be other ways to counter the situation, but I think this can work too.

Comment: Module as you suggested :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162442/how-to-import-md5-password-to-magento-2/162480 ,is ok for MD5 but my password are SHA1 format,how we can achieve for SHA1?